# Windows 10 PC cannot play MP3 files from android LG G3 with 0 bytes

Tags: usb, sd-card, windows, lg-g3, mp3

I was trying to edit one of my sound files on my phone in audacity eariler today, when I discovered that the files held "0 bytes" and were inaccessible by any players on hand.

Info:

- LG G3 does not charge using stock charger
- Windows 10's windows media player fails to play MP3s
- MP3s are playable using stock android player
- Windows explorer shows problem files as "0 bytes"
- MP3s are stored on SD Card

Attempted fixes:

- Restarting phone/PC
- Replacing USB cable

  - Cable from Amazon Fire tablet opens on windows but no consistent MP3 file access
- Switching PCs
- Cleaning Parts
- Removing and reinserting SD card
- Using VLC to play files
- Using Audacity to play files
- Moving/Copying files to desktop
- Uninstalling/Reinstalling Android driver
- Enabling USB Debugging

EDIT 4/29/2016: Tried using Windows 8.1 and a Chromebook, but former came up as zero and no Internal/SD card detected on the latter.

EDIT 5/2/2016: Just realized that the problem MP3s are also listed as "Size: Unknown" in the default android music app. However, they still play normally.

Comment: Does copying using card reader make a difference?

Comment: Was you phone unlocked as you did this, or sitting on the side with the screen off?

Comment: Also, if files are in SDCARD, did you SD Adapter to view files in PC?

Comment: I tried using two SD card adapters and my laptop's card reader. No files were shown and no windows opened even after reinstalling the drivers for it. So basically nothing happened
I did have to leave the screen on so that I could press allow on the USB permission prompt on the LG G3, but I don't remember any sort of change because of the screen being on.

Comment: Try this...go to and File-Upload website from your phone, and try to upload one of your songs. Now go to your PC and download it.
Check what happens...

Comment: Strange. That worked. I uploaded a song from my phone to Google Drive and it played in both the browser and in WMP after download. Still doesn't work over a cable, however.